# SQL statement question - how to retrieve data from 2 linked tables

Tags: mysql, sql

pretty new with SQL stuff, I have a question regarding a SQL statement.

I have a filter, when you select a user, it shows all the items regarding that user.
For this I have a table called `TblItem` (which the PK is `ItemID`), and there I have a UserID column, 
so retrieving all the items with `UserID = Selected User` is pretty straightforward.

Now I need to go a step further.

I have a second table, called `TblItemTask`, which has a foreign key: `ItemTaskItemID` which is linked to the PK of the first table `ItemID`

So each item can have multiple tasks, and each task is assigned to a User.

So now when I select a user, I don't want only to show the Items regarding that user, I also want to show Items that are linked to another user, BUT have some tasks assigned to the selected user!

For example, I select user `150`, I should have displayed now this:

```
Item 1 with UserID = 150;
Item 2 with UserID = 150;
Item 3 with UserID = 220;
```

in this example, `Item 3` has a task that is assigned to `UserID = 150`, that's why it must be shown

These are the tables:

```
TblItem = [ItemID (PK), ItemDescription, ItemUserID]

TblItemTask [TaskID (PK), ItemTaskItemID (FK), ItemTaskUserID]
```

I tried this SQL but it only retrieves the Items where the task's UserID matches the selected user, it doesnt display the Items linked to that UserID:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ItemID,
    ItemDescription,
    ItemUserID
FROM
    dbo.TblItem
INNER JOIN dbo.TblItemtask ON
ItemID = ItemtaskItemID
WHERE ItemUserID = [user_selected_my_items] OR ItemTaskUserID = [user_selected_my_items]
```

I had to add `DISTINCT` because if an Item has 4 tasks assigned to an user, that Item would be shown 4 times in my list, and I need it to be displayed only once as it's the same item

**EDIT: 
Solved, I was using INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN, once I changed that from my SQL statement, everything is working correctly!**

Comment: hello, what do you mean? I provided a sample and I also described how the result should look like! Let me know how I can improve these informations

Comment: An example of the data in your source tables would be very helpful (rather than just the schema)

Comment: Ok, good to know for the next time, as I found the answer, I was using INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN! Sorry for probably a dumb question, still learning

Comment: Even those of us who have learned a lot occasionally ask dumb questions :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to that left join, I think you just need a subquery in your where clause...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ItemID,
    ItemDescription,
    ItemUserID
FROM
    dbo.TblItem
LEFT JOIN dbo.TblItemtask ON
ItemID = ItemtaskItemID
WHERE ItemUserID = [user_selected_my_items] OR ItemID in (Select itemTaskItemID from tblitemtask)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, could you explain me what s the difference in adding this subquery? from a quick test it seems my SQL statement was working as it is!

Comment: You're right. Not a blind bit of difference. The subquery would have worked around the inner join, but with the left join you don't need it.